# Script/API - Snap selection to grid, but only one axis

Tags: python, scripting, snapping, axis

by script I can do a snap-to-grid of the selected vertices:

```
bpy.context.space_data.grid_scale = 0.125
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_grid()
```

But I need to restrain it to one axis ... but how?

Many thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

**Ditch the operator**

IMO far simpler to ditch the operator and round the desired axis component to the nearest gradation.

Test script, Run in edit mode, moves all selected verts local z coordinate to nearest multiple of 0.125

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

grid_spacing = 0.125

sel_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

for v in sel_verts:
    v.co.z = round(v.co.z / grid_spacing) * grid_spacing

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Considering the grid to be a global system, will convert the vert coordinate to global `mw @ v.co` find the nearest gradation point, then convert back to local `mwi @ v.co`

Please Note script written for and tested on 2.8. For prior replace  `@` with `*`

```
import bpy
import bmesh


context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
mw = ob.matrix_world
mwi = mw.inverted()
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

grid_spacing = 0.125

sel_verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

for v in sel_verts:
    g = mw @ v.co # use * prior 2.8
    g.z = round(g.z / grid_spacing) * grid_spacing
    v.co = mwi @ g

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, batFINGER. I had so chance to test it yet but I found my own workarount by simply looping over all selected verts and storing their x,y position and after applying the snap to grid, restore them.